# Connecting logging events between docker containers

Tags: spring-boot, docker, logging, containers

For the first time I am working in an environment where we deploy components in multiple docker containers. The log files in each component are indexed by splunk. In our example we have a legacy JSP app running in container A that invokes restful API deployed in container B (spring-boot). The issue I am running into is connecting the user request in container A to the restful API in container B.

Basically I want a cohesive sequential view of all the code that was executed to process a user's request. I think I will have to log using some type of unique identifier that is attached to a user but shared across all containers. Is there some established pattern to do this?

Comment: Both propagating some kind of transaction ID between requests (an `X-Request-Id:` HTTP header, for example) and setting up a distributed tracing system are common enough.  The [Istio distributed tracing documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/) has a basic description of typical changes you'd need in your application code.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thank you so very much!